# How to sort UniqueValues in a filter dropdown in ascending order in React

Tags: reactjs, serverless, airtable

I am new to React and have been unable to find a solution to sorting uniquevalues in a filter. I have a filter dropdown that lists UniqueValues (years) with the data coming from an Airtable serverless function. I would like to sort the years in ascending order. Currently, this is how the filter displays the years, in random order:

[image]

This is my code from Filter.js page. To be clear the filter I am trying to sort is year :

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { useFilterContext } from "../context/filter_context";
import { getUniqueValues, formatPrice } from "../utils/helpers";
import { FaCheck } from "react-icons/fa";

const Filters = () => {
  const {
    filters: { text, year, shape, themecamp, official },
    updateFilters,
    all_products,
    clearFilters,
  } = useFilterContext();

  const years = getUniqueValues(all_products, "year");
  const shapes = getUniqueValues(all_products, "shape");

  return (
   <Wrapper>
      <div className="content">
        <form onSubmit={(e) => e.preventDefault()}>
          {/* start search input */}
          <div className="form-control">
            <input
              type="text"
              name="text"
              placeholder="search"
              className="search-input"
              value={text}
              onChange={updateFilters}
            />
          </div>
          {/* end of search input */}
          {/* start clear filters */}
          <button type="button" className="clear-btn" onClick={clearFilters}>
            clear filters
          </button>
          {/* end clear filters */}
          {/* start year */}
          <div className="form-control">
            <h5>year</h5>
            <select
              name="year"
              value={year}
              onChange={updateFilters}
              className="year"
            >
              {years.map((stickeryear, index) => {
                return (
                  <option key={index} value={stickeryear}>
                    {stickeryear}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
         </div>
          {/* end of year */}
          {/* sticker shape */}
          <div className="form-control">
            <h5>sticker shape</h5>
            <select
              name="shape"
              value={shape}
              onChange={updateFilters}
              className="shape"
            >
              {shapes.map((c, index) => {
                return (
                  <option key={index} value={c}>
                    {c}
                  </option>
                );
              })}
            </select>
          </div>
          {/* end sticker shape */}
          {/* start themecamp */}
          <div className="form-control themecamp">
            <label htmlFor="themecamp">Theme Camps</label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              name="themecamp"
              id="themecamp"
              checked={themecamp}
              onChange={updateFilters}
            />
          </div>
      {/* end of  themecamp */}
      {/* start official sticker */}
      <div className="form-control themecamp">
        <label htmlFor="official">"Official sticker"</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="official"
          id="official"
          checked={official}
          onChange={updateFilters}
        />
      </div>
      {/* end of official sticker */}
    </form>
  </div>
</Wrapper>
  );
};



export default Filters;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding:

```
years.sort(compareYears);

  function compareYears(a, b) {
    return b - a;
  }
```